# time_out MySQL WARN при запуске с майнкрафт плагином

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, плагин, mysql-workbench, minecraft

проблема задержек данных при коннекте плагина и MySQL
have a problem with coonect minecraft plugin to MySQL without phpMyAdmin panel
console give it -

[21:03:19 WARN]: [com.bencodez.votingplugin.advancedcore.hikari.pool.PoolBase] HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@1c98015 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.

нашёл ответ в интернете что мне нужно выставить задержку в MySQL как у плагина (поднять time_out) но не понимаю где это сделать нужно, как мне найти и изменить настройки БД?
у Hikari задержка 30 мин, а MySQL 10, где и какое значение выставить необходимо для синхронизации чтобы ошибка пропала?

Comment: Если что у меня dedicated сервер windows с удалённым доступом через окно
установлен MySQL и phpMyAdmin, OpenServer, всё что мне нужно в помощи - объяснить где открыть функционал настроек MySQL чтобы изменить настройки time_out

Comment: вот зарубежный ответ про задержки, на это я ссылаюсь ибо ничего другого не нашёл.
The problem is that the default value of the spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime (30 minutes - https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) is higher than the database's "wait_timeout" (10 minutes in my case).
So you have two options, either decrease the hikari.maxLifetime below 10 minutes, or increase the database's "wait_timeout" property.